# Youtube Subscription list to text file

Tags: youtube, dropbox, youtube-dl

I want to have an up-to-date text file in my Drop box folder with the URL of all my you tube subscriptions, I've tried using the stock "If You tube then Drop box" but couldn't find what I needed, another website pointed me in the direction of the Maker Channel, but I was unable to figure out how to tailor that to my needs. If I could have a recipe that stated "If (New You tube subscription) then (Append to Drop box text file)" that would be perfect, I've looked for about an hour and can't find anything

PS: if there is a Linux command that would do this, that would be a lot easier, but I can't find this either.
PPS: it's to use with the Linux command "youtube-dl" so if there's already an option in there to just use a subscription list and I'm just not seeing it, please let me know.

Comment: The page https://www.youtube.com/subscription_manager lists your subscriptions. The page's source contains them. A script that extracts it from the downloaded page can be cooked up using wget, but you'll need to log in first. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324421/how-to-get-past-the-login-page-with-wget how to set up cookies with wget. You'll probably need to put it into cron to update regularly.

Comment: @Dugi I'd be surprised if you could simply login to YouTube using cookies. You will probably need some OAUTH2 authentication for that. Then, it is just a question of calling the `youtube.subscriptions().list()` method in a your programming language of choice.

Comment: The third reply on the link I've posted explains how to do exactly that. There is a chrome extension that allows exporting all cookies into a file and that file can be fed to wget.

Comment: All I need is a text file with he URL of each channel I've subscribed to on a new line. At the moment I've found the command "ytsubs" which lets me add the line ":ytsubs" or ":ytsubscriptions" to my current batch file, and it does what I need it to, but I'd much prefer to have a list of URLs... I like to organise it

Comment: @Dugi but that works only when you are *already* logged in to Youtube through Chrome, which does the OAUTH2 authentication for you. I'd like to see that done in one standalone command.

Comment: @Jos In most cases, getting access to a computer that can open Chrome that you would use to log in to youtube to save the cookies is trivial.